# Problem by Url.Action in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url.action

I have a problem by Url.Action in asp.net MVC.
this is a sample:

```
Url.Action("index", new { page = 1, success = 2});
```

This code generate this url `index?page=1&amp;success=2`
In this url there is `&amp;` instead of `&` character.
because of this problem `Request.QueryString["success"]` return null.
What is the solution?
Note: Im using Url.Action and Request.QueryString in a view not a controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem is encoding

You're probably using `<%: %>` but you should be using `<%= %>` so result will not get encoded.

So instead of writing:

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("index", new { page = 1, success = 2}) %>">My link</a>
```

you should convert to:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("index", new { page = 1, success = 2}) %>">My link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably html-encoding the output of the Url.Action.

Can you post code about where and how you use the result? Because the method itself should return the value as you expect it.